# Is rand.Next(randSeed.Next(1,10), randSeed2.Next(10, 20)) more random than rand.Next(1,20)?

Tags: c#, .net, random, numbers

Is rand.Next(randSeed.Next(1,10), randSeed2.Next(10, 20)) more random than rand.Next(1,20)?

I'm always getting the same number from the random class when i run code every 10 minutes (using a timer from the system.timers.timer class)

Comment: What are you using to seed your Random object? (rand) If you always use the same seed, and you're re-initializing the object every time 10 minutes, it'll keep giving the same random number.

Comment: please try searching first: there are a gazillion similar questions

Comment: wow that was nearly instant.  I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251714/c-sharp-random-numbers-arent-being-random?rq=1 but i still need an answer to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A seed is used to initialize a random number generator, like so:

```
Random rand = new Random(1234);  // 1234 is the seed.
```

Or to make it different each time your program is run, you can do this:

```
Random rand = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks);  // Use current time for seed.
```

or simply:

```
Random rand = new Random();  // If you don't specify a seed, it uses the current time by default.
```

Note: If you use a fixed seed number, then you will get the same sequences of output from `Rand()` each time after initialization.

Only *after* the seed initialization do you start to use the random number generator normally (such as calling `Next()`). In other words, seeds are not supposed to be used as parameters of `Next()`.

If, however, you are trying to make the seed itself more 'random' by using *another* random number generator to produce it, then don't bother. Mathematically, this won't be any more random. You are better off using a cryptographic random number generator instead, such as [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**Note:** Although cryptographic random number generators are more 'random', they are also slower.

Comment: Thanks, this'll solve my problem, but i would like an answer to my initial question. (Is rand.Next(randSeed.Next(1,10), randSeed2.Next(10, 20)) more random than rand.Next(1,20)?)

Comment: @Dev, why do you ask? If you don't need cryptographic-level randomness, then there is no difference. If you do, neither are acceptably random.

Comment: @Dev As I mentioned in my answer: "_Mathematically, this won't be any more random._"