# How could I assign a random enum value in constructor?

Tags: c#, oop

since I have the code below

```
public class student
{
    public enum Level
    {
        novice,
        adept,
        master
    }
    private Level _skillevel;
    public student()
    {
      _skillevel = 
      //to assign a random value from novice, adept and master
     }
```

what I expect is that each time a student object created, it will be assign a random skill level. How could I exeucte it? thanks for helps.

Comment: Really similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132126/how-do-i-select-a-random-value-from-an-enumeration

Comment: sorry about the repetiton, I will delete it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a random value of enum

```
 public student()
    {
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Level));
        Random random = new Random();
        Level _skillevel = (Level)values.GetValue(random.Next(values.Length));
    }
```

If you are planning to create the object of student in a loop then it is advisable to keep object of Random class as static.

Comment: @YunxiangLi If that is correct then don't forget to accept this as correct answer :)

Comment: I advise you to pass in the `Random` object as a parameter and not create it inside the method. Otherwise if you call it more than once every few milliseconds, it won't be properly random. [Create a `Random` once somewhere, and pass it around.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7251724/106159)

Comment: @MatthewWatson, Right the correct method would be passing the random variable in constructor, but then also I would advice to keep the Random variable as static in some static class