# Cannot evaluate expression c#

Tags: c#

I'm getting the below error at `var okColors = colors.ToArray();`

> Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.

Can you please help on this?

```
    private Color GetRandomColor()
    {
        Random randomGen = new Random();
        Color randomColor = Color.Red;

        KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
        KnownColor[] badColors = { KnownColor.AliceBlue };
        IEnumerable<KnownColor> colors = names.Except(badColors);

        var okColors = colors.ToArray();

        KnownColor randomColorName = okColors[randomGen.Next(okColors.Length)];
        randomColor = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);
        if (!ColorsList.Contains(randomColor) && !randomColor.Name.Contains("Light"))
            ColorsList.Add(randomColor);
        else
            GetRandomColor();
        return randomColor;
    }
```

Comment: can you post your class defenitions?

Comment: I think you have an infinite recursion to `GetRandomColor` that is resulting in a stack overflow.  Since you're creating a new `Random` each time the method is called, and `Random` is seeded based on the current time, your code keeps selecting the same color over and over again and eventually overflows the stack.

Comment: And entirely apart from the issue of re-using `Random`, if you generate too many colours, you'll always hit infinite recursion because every colour is found is `ColorsList`. This will happen even if you fix the problem with random.

Comment: Definition for 'KnownColor' is? and '.Contains' always give array of values make sure it should not be null.

Answer (score 2):

Your code throws StackOverflowException and when it happens debugger can no longer evaluate any variables resulting in error you see.

Why code have `StackOverflowException`:

- code uses wrong way to generate random number and ends up with the same number for enough calls. Correct way - [How do I generate a random int number in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706500/how-do-i-generate-a-random-int-number-in-c) - use static `Random` instance.
- as result checks for `.Contains` constantly fail and code essentially becomes infinite recursion:

  ```
  private Color GetRandomColor()
  {
    if (true) return GetRandomColor();
  }
  ```

Additional reading: [How do I prevent and/or handle a StackOverflowException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206820/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-handle-a-stackoverflowexception)

Answer (score 2):

You have to **use the same instance of Random** for each recursive call, do not create a new one in each function call. If a new Random instance is created in the function every time it's called, you might keep getting the same values and not random values as you might expect.

Here is [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7251724/4583393) you might want to look at:

> randomNumber creates a new instance of Random each time... which in
>   turn creates a new pseudo-random number generator based on the current
>   time... which doesn't change as often as you might think.

In the linked thread, Jon Skeet also **suggested against using a static Random** variable.

> Use the same instance of Random repeatedly... but don't "fix" it by
>   creating a static Random variable. That won't work well either in the
>   long term, as Random isn't thread-safe.

One option can be to pass an instance of Random as parameter to the function, this would ensure that the same Random instance is being passed along the recursive chain:

```
private Color GetRandomColor(Random randomGen = new Random())
{
    Color randomColor = Color.Red;

    KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
    KnownColor[] badColors = { KnownColor.AliceBlue };
    IEnumerable<KnownColor> okColors = names.Except(badColors).ToArray();

    KnownColor randomColorName = okColors[randomGen.Next(okColors.Length)];
    randomColor = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);

    if (!ColorsList.Contains(randomColor) && !randomColor.Name.Contains("Light"))
    {
        ColorsList.Add(randomColor);
    }
    else
    {
        GetRandomColor(randomGen);
    }

    return randomColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code continuously hitting the `else` part.
Please check your `if()..else()` condition

Answer (score 0):

The following function will work for you.

```
    List<Color> ColorsList = new List<Color>();
    private Color GetRandomColor(Random randomGen)
            {
                Color randomColor = Color.Red;
                KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
                KnownColor[] badColors = { KnownColor.AliceBlue };            
                IEnumerable<KnownColor> colors = names.Except(badColors);
                colors = colors.ToArray().Except(ColorsList.Select(x => x.ToKnownColor()));
                KnownColor[] okColors = colors.ToArray();
                KnownColor randomColorName = okColors[randomGen.Next(okColors.Length)];
                randomColor = Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);

                if (!ColorsList.Contains(randomColor))
                {
                    ColorsList.Add(randomColor);
                    if (okColors.Count() == 1)
                    {
                        ColorsList.Clear();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    GetRandomColor(randomGen);
                }

                return randomColor;
            }
```

To call this function

```
GetRandomColor(new Random())
```

As many stated above the issue was due to infinite recursion call of GetRandomColor function. To fix it, I have removed already fetched random colors from okColor list. Also after getting all colors, i have cleared the ColorsList to continue the randomization.